# SSL module is not available error installing pyodbc for python

Tags: python, ssl, pip, pycharm, pyodbc

I had to import the `pyodbc` library and for that I have executed

```bash
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pyodbc
```

and the following error is received:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyodbc (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyodbc
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

My pip version is: pip 24.0 and python version: Python 3.7.1
(i'm using windows 10)

I tried to reinstall Python and checked “Add python.exe to path” and it didn't help. I should note that in the past I used an older version of Python and did not get this error.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that pyodbc Requires: Python >=3.8. So you need to upgrade your current version** See https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/#data

First, if you're not already using one, you should consider using [Python virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/).

Then [install pyodbc on your Windows](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install#installing-on-windows) machine:

> Try `pip install pyodbc` first. This should "just work" in the vast majority of cases. pip will download the correct pyodbc wheel for your PC/Python set up and install it.
> If for some reason you need to build pyodbc from source — e.g., if `pip install pyodbc` downloads a source distribution like "pyodbc-4.0.35.tar.gz" instead of a pre-built wheel (.whl) file — then make sure you have the appropriate C++ compiler on your PC. Look [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Building-pyodbc-from-source#windows) for details on that.

Comment: I tried `pip install pyodbc` but still the same error

Comment: You need to upgrade your python version

Comment: I've updated my answer. The latest version was released a few hours ago. You need python 3.8 or greater to install pyodbc. See https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/#data